# Gnuradio Macports fresh install - segmentation fault 11

Tags: python, macos, macports

I'm really frustrated with this.  **Here's info that may be relevant...**

1. Macbook - mid 2015 - i7 2.5Ghz - 16 Gb RAM OSX Sierra 10.12.4
2. a 256 Gb Solid State Drive. **[ Fusion Drive ]**
3. **A Tardisk has been installed to increase the overall hard drive capacity  **<-- could this be the problem?? After reformatting fusion drive, is it possible that the memory mapping is off?**

Also, keep in mind that I've successfully installed gnuradio on this exact same computer several times over the past 3 months and has always worked quite well.

** Running 'gnuradio-companion' immediately yields a Segmentation Fault 11 error and Python is opened, but quickly closed.**

*Now, I've carefully repeated the entire install process 3 times now*.  I downloaded Macports, X11 Quartz, and edited .bash_profile to the correct paths.

I even tried installing on another high end mac desktop and surprisingly the dismal results persist with the exact same seg. fault 11 error.

==========================================================================

```
'Segmentation Fault: 11' 

Process:               Python [84191]
Path:                  /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            Python
Version:               2.7.13 (2.7.13)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        bash [84087]
Responsible:           Python [84191]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2017-05-01 03:02:17.044 -0400
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.4 (16E195)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        96FA6318-4AB4-AFA3-AA76-44665346EF38

Sleep/Wake UUID:       9A6E29A2-5A15-4F3C-A2C8-CDFAAABE5BBD

Time Awake Since Boot: 21000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       20000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000008
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]
```

Possible Fixes?

Also, I've tested replacing '/opt/local/' with a working directory from a previous install and it loads right up, but other errors arise on compile/run of flowcharts.

This is so frustrating considering I've successfully installed macports several times on this exact macbook and it worked perfect.

It seems this seg. fault error is fairly common, but this only makes finding a specific fix more difficult.  I tried to research this but, I wasn't able to find any relevant suggestions.

==========================================================================

Comment: i also get this error with a fresh mac install. installing gnuradio on a mac always seem to be painful and time consuming.

Comment: What about taking the "/opt/" directory of my working desktop install (it also runs Sierra) and splicing it somehow?  If not, could I duplicate the entire desktop Sierra install in a time machine backup or something and transfer it?
Otherwise, I know VM's would be the way to go, but the workflow feels so awkward and there's a tendency for lag.

Comment: I have never tried `gnuradio` itself, but it is available via **homebrew** and I have never had a single problem with any **homebrew** packages in many years of use.

Comment: There are some things I like about homebrew vs macports.  My impression is that at one time macports provided more packages and was a more stable install forg gnuradio, but as far as I can tell now its pretty even.  I'm going to go for brew install gnuradio and see what happens.

Comment: I'm thinking the error might be from OSX's security where you have to approve new applications if they aren't from certain developers.  I ran Gnuradio-Companion from a pre-compiled version and I noticed I got a warning about security. I set it to 'open anyway' in Security & Privacy and then it opened GRC just fine.  With this new insight I did another delete and clean (with --dist) and reinstall.  Now, I'm back to 'build failed' in macports...I can't understand how this can be so inconsistent!  I feel like dropping this  from a tall building at this point...

Comment: @zodiacTiger actually homebrew is way more popular than macports these days. `brew install gnuradio` _just works_.

Answer (score 0):

An update to cppunit broke gnuradio, it's currently being fixed.

See here: https://trac.macports.org/ticket/54078

Comment: Thanks so much for letting me know.  At least now I can stop the lengthy OS reinstalls and alternate gnuradio installs, etc. and makes me feel better!!  Hopefully it gets fixed soon.